# How to compare a list of similar strings in python for sport games?

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

I have a list of dictionaries of sports games with various attributes.  These lists are all made with only one sport in the list.  So I have a basketball games list, baseball games list, etc.

I want to format all of the "game" values the same way so the same particular sports match (Pit Steelers vs LA Rams) for example all have the same string value.  Examples of a  particular game could be `"PIT Steelers vs LA Rams"` but this also could be formatted `"Pittsburgh Steelers vs Los Angeles Rams"`. I may have up to 7 dictionaries within the list for a particular game formatted in slightly different ways.

I can't choose to just use the team name or the city because within the same sport there could be the same match with those particular team names or cities just in two different leagues like the NFL and the NCAA.

I was thinking I would use the most expansive game name as the key.  For example, I would use `"Pittsburgh Steelers vs Los Angeles Rams"` instead of `"PIT Steelers vs LA Rams"` as the key to use as a baseline.

Is there a way I could compare these other matches to the key and say if there is above X percentage of this string in the key replace this string game with the key?  How would you do it?  I am open to all suggestions!

Thanks!

Edit: Here is an attempt using difflib.  I generated 1000 random games and imported into excel and sorted by ratio.  We can see that it isn't a perfect fit.

[image]

Comment: You could try splitting on the 'vs' part and apply Levenshtein distance. But it doesn't seem very robust. I think the best way would be to have a dictionary with all the possible variants: `teams = {"PIT Steelers": ["PIT Steelers", "Pittsburgh Steelers"], "other team": ["variant1", "variant2"]}`

Comment: It depends on how you define _similar_. For example, is "crab" similar to "crap"?

Comment: Since I am scraping these from third-party websites for me to have a dictionary of all sports with all possible variants is nearly impossible.

Comment: I'd say if like 75% or so of the smaller variant chars were found in the key expansive variant I would probably say with decent confidence they are a match.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem to solve - you could try to accumulate a table of all the aliases for a team, point these aliases to a chosen key, and look up a team via the aliases. The building of the table will either require human intervention, or some complex machinery... You can try to short cut the complexity with the 75% match that you indicate, and maybe it works well, it is hard to tell.

Comment: Seems like difflib may be an option looking at other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: I tried difflib and it may be usable if I add a bunch of "if" statements check out my edit of the main post above and let me know if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a list of short team names that doesn't include the city, then scan the title for those short names. You should find two short team names in each title, which you can then use for grouping the titles into unique games.

```
team_long_names = ['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears',
         'Dallas Cowboys', 'Detriot Lions','Green Bay Packers','Los Angeles Rams',
         'Minnesota Vikings','New Orleans Saints','New York Giants', 'Philadelphia Eagles',
         'San Francisco 49ers','Seattle Seahawks','Washington Redskins','Baltimore Ravens',
         'Buffalo Bills','Cinncinnati Bangals','Cleveland Browns','Denver Broncos',
         'Houston Texans','Indanapolis Colts','Jacksonville Jaguars','Kansas City Chiefs',
         'Las Vegas Raiders','Los Angeles Chargers','Miami Dolphins','New England Patriots',
         'New York Jets','Pittsburgh Steelers','Tennessee Titans']

team_short_names = [n.lower().split(' ')[-1] for n in team_long_names]

game_titles = ['Atlanta Falcons vs New York Jets', 'ATL Falcons vs NY Jets', 'Falcons v Jets',
            'SF 49ers vs PIT Steelers', 'San Fransico 49ers vs Pittsburg Steelers', '49ers vs Steelers',
            'Dallas Cowboys vs LA Chargers', 'DAL Cowboys vs Los Angles Chargers', 'Cowboys v Chargers',
            'Blah blah Falcons and Foo bar Jets']

titles_by_key = []

for title in game_titles:
    game_key = '-'.join([word for word in title.lower().split(' ') if word in team_short_names])
    titles_by_key.append(game_key + ": " + title)

print(sorted(titles_by_key))
```

Output:

```
['49ers-steelers: 49ers vs Steelers',
 '49ers-steelers: SF 49ers vs PIT Steelers',
 '49ers-steelers: San Fransico 49ers vs Pittsburg Steelers',
 'cowboys-chargers: Cowboys v Chargers',
 'cowboys-chargers: DAL Cowboys vs Los Angles Chargers',
 'cowboys-chargers: Dallas Cowboys vs LA Chargers',
 'falcons-jets: ATL Falcons vs NY Jets',
 'falcons-jets: Atlanta Falcons vs New York Jets',
 'falcons-jets: Blah blah Falcons and Foo bar Jets',
 'falcons-jets: Falcons v Jets']
```

That doesn't solve the problem of possible team name collisions with different leagues, but I suspect there might be easier strategies for detecting the league as a pre-processing step.

Comment: I think you are right.  I tried a bunch of different difflib strategies but if you can break it up into leagues then you can just use the team names and you can be certain there are no false positives.

Comment: But even then I am sure there are NCAA teams with the same names.  I am curious about how aggregator websites deal with this issue.

Comment: I don't think this is a perfect solution but I do agree with how you tackling it for known leagues that are not likely to change.  I am going to use your rationale here for all leagues that are unlikely to change team names such as the main professional sports.  Then I will likely use difflib and if statements to try to figure out matches for different sports.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [fuzzy wuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) library to replace the strings. Make a main list of the teams, then you can use the fuzzy wuzzy package to extract the team most similar to the other strings. It won't be perfect though, as you'll need to test out different scenarios, for example `'CAR'` won't return `Carolina Panthers`, it'll return `'Arizona Cardinals'`, and `'LVR'` came back with `'Los Angels Rams'`. So you'dd just have to pay, and then possibly for those few cases, just work out some logic to get back the right team.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

nfl_teams = ['Arizona Cardinals', 'Atlanta Falcons', 'Carolina Panthers', 'Chicago Bears',
         'Dallas Cowboys', 'Detriot Lions','Green Bay Packers','Los Angeles Rams',
         'Minnesota Vikings','New Orleans Saints','New York Giants', 'Philadelphia Eagles',
         'San Francisco 49ers','Seattle Seahawks','Washington Redskins','Baltimore Ravens',
         'Buffalo Bills','Cinncinnati Bangals','Cleveland Browns','Denver Broncos',
         'Houston Texans','Indanapolis Colts','Jacksonville Jaguars','Kansas City Chiefs',
         'Las Vegas Raiders','Los Angeles Chargers','Miami Dolphins','New England Patriots',
         'New York Jets','Pittsburgh Steelers','Tennessee Titans']

matchups = ['OAK Raiders vs CHI Bears','GB Packers vs MIN Vikings','PIT Steelers vs LA Rams', 'PHI vs DEN']
for each in matchups:
    team1, team2 = each.split('vs')[0].strip(), each.split('vs')[-1].strip()
    team1_alpha = process.extractOne(team1, nfl_teams)[0]
    team2_alpha = process.extractOne(team2, nfl_teams)[0]
    
    print ('%s ----->   %s vs %s' %(each, team1_alpha, team2_alpha))
```

**Output:**

```
OAK Raiders vs CHI Bears ----->   Las Vegas Raiders vs Chicago Bears
GB Packers vs MIN Vikings ----->   Green Bay Packers vs Minnesota Vikings
PIT Steelers vs LA Rams ----->   Pittsburgh Steelers vs Los Angeles Rams
PHI vs DEN ----->   Philadelphia Eagles vs Denver Broncos
```

Or if you do want to do a compare to check to see how similar they are.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
var1 = "Pittsburgh Steelers vs Los Angeles Rams" 
var2 = "PIT Steelers vs LA Rams"

print(fuzz.ratio(var1, var2))  

print(fuzz.token_sort_ratio(var1, var2))

print(fuzz.token_set_ratio(var1, var2))
```

**Output:**

```
68
71
82
```

Comment: What are the perks to fuzzy wuzzy vs difflib?

Comment: I never used difflib, but looks like it's essentially the same. I see your results. It might help if you split on the `'vs'` and reconstruct that way.